# Retrieving from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem retrieving a desired object in the ArrayList.
Instead of getting the desired object, I got the others from the ArrayList.

This is my ArrayList:

```
public Database () {
    this.mPatient=new ArrayList();
    mPatient.add(new Patient("Dummy", "S11111", 12345, "No", "9march" ));

    this.mService=new ArrayList();
    mService.add(new Service("Dentist", 1.2345, 74.12345,"Dental Services"));
    mService.add(new Service("Eye Center", 2.2345, 75.12345,"Specialist"));
    mService.add(new Service("Hospital", 12.2345, 90.12345,"Cancer Service"));
    mService.add(new Service("Hospital", 14.2345, 91.12345,"Cardiac Service"));
    mService.add(new Service("Hospital", 8.2345, 76.12345,"Skin Care"));
}
```

I have a button that will retrieve the services.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       double plat = Double.valueOf(jTextField6.getText());
       double plon = Double.valueOf(jTextField7.getText());

       jTextArea1.setText(controller.getLocation(plat, plon));
}
```

This is my getLocation method:

```
public String getLocation (double lat, double lon) {
    ArrayList<Service> allService = mDatabase.retLocation(lat, lon);

    String finaldata="";

    for(int i=0; i<allService.size();i++)
    {
         Service tempService = allService.get(i);
         finaldata += tempService.getDetail();
    }
    return finaldata;
}
```

and my retrieveLocation method.

```
public ArrayList<Service> retLocation (double lat, double lon) {
    ArrayList<Service> allservice = new ArrayList<Service>();
    for(int i=0; i<mService.size();i++)
    {
        Service tempService = mService.get(i);
        if(tempService.getLat()>=lat+5 &&tempService.getLon()>=lon+5)
        {
            allservice.add(tempService);
        }
    }
    return allservice;
}
```

I wanted to get service "Dentist, Dental Services" and "Eye Center, Specialist" as the output so I input the Latitude as 1 and Longtitude as 74 as in the JTextField.

Instead I got "Hospital, Cancer Service" and "Hospital, Cardiac Service" as he output.

Comment: `if(tempService.getLat()>=lat+5 &&tempService.getLon()>=lon+5) ` you add an offset of `5` to the latitude and longitude and it matches  `Hospital, Cancer Service` and `Hospital, Cardiac Service`

Comment: you're adding 5 to latitude and longitude, thats why for the input lat 1 & long 74, you're getting all values with `lat >= 6 && long >= 79`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lat+5 and lon+5 is your problem. with lat=1+5 you get past the eye center lat and the dentist lat so these are for sure not returned. I imagine that you want to give a position and get the nearby services, so why dont you use

```
 if(tempService.getLat()<=lat+5 &&tempService.getLon()<=lon+5)
```

instead of

```
 if(tempService.getLat()>=lat+5 &&tempService.getLon()>=lon+5)
```

? it will return services in the range of your given lat+5, lon+5.

if you want a range like lat 1-5 and lon 70-80:

```
 if(tempService.getLat()<=5 && 
    tempService.getLat()>=1 && 
     tempService.getLon()<=80 &&
       tempService.getLon()>=70 )
```

Comment: What if I want to get services within a range? 
For example Lat between 1 and 5 and Lon between 70 and 80?
Cause from the given example I can only get either more than the number I input or less.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but don't you want to look at a range of lat and lon? something like,

```
 for(int i=0; i<mService.size();i++) {
    Service tempService = mService.get(i);
    double tempLat = tempService.getLat();
    double tempLon = tempService.getLon();

    // DELTA_LAT and DELTA_LON are both constants possibly = to 5
    if(tempLat <= lat + DELTA_LAT && tempLat >= lat - DELTA_LAT && 
       tempLon <= lon + DELTA_LON && tempLon >= lon - DELTA_LON) {
           allservice.add(tempService);
    }
 }
```

This code would identify all services within a rectangle 2 * DELTA_LAT (10) units high by 2 * DELTA_LON (10) units wide, centered at lat and lon.

Since lat and lon are doubles you can't find exact matches, and I doubt that you want a listing of all services that are > a certain location, but rather aren't you searching for all services that are ***close*** to a certain location? If so, then the above code should work, and the closeness would be set by the DELTA_LAT and DELTA_LON constants (which you can combine into a single DELTA constant if desired).